# Error type Object doesnt support this kind of property or method on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

Why is my following code not working in Internet Explorer? It work fine in Firefox. I get "object doesnt support this kind of property or method." Please help. Following is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcmrc() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('mrc');
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var input = inputs[i];
            var num = Number(input.value);
            if (isNaN(num)) {
                alert('Please Enter a valid number: ' + input.value);
                num = 0;
            }
            sum += num;
        }
        document.getElementById('mrcresult').value = '$' + sum;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is not supported in early browsers:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('mrc');
```

[IE8 and earlier dont support it](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)

If you are new to javascript you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to help work around that

using jquery:

```
var inputs = $('.mrc');
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does [not](http://caniuse.com/#search=getelementsbyclassname) support [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName).

To support in in IE8, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484509/1048572), for earlier versions see [getElementsByClassName() doesn't work in old Internet Explorers like IE6, IE7, IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6584635/1048572)