# Targeting class name - "Object doesn't support property or method"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE 8: Object doesn’t support property or method ‘getElementsByClassName’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484467/ie-8-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-getelementsbyclassname)

I've got a table with generated divs placed within each td, each have a generated classname example: "c1" I can drag say "c1" to another cell I want it to update the textbox (class = cell).

```
alert(target_cell.className);

//var cellTxt = target_cell.querySelectorAll('.cell');       
var cellTxt = target_cell.getElementsByClassName('cell')[0];

cellTxt.setAttribute('value', target_cell.className);
alert(cellTxt.value);
```

The target_cell is the new cell but it throws up the error "Object doesn't support property or method" when it tries to update it. I get the same error in IE 8 & 9 using either cellTxt options.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Also there's no reason to use `.setAttribute()` to set the "value" property of a DOM element - just write `cellTxt.value = whatever;`

Comment: I think your problem is cellTxt is not an input type of element. Use `innerHTML` as I suggest below.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of cellTxt if it is the text box.

```
cellTxt.value = Anything;
```

Comment: cell is an input element inside div "c1"

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName() is not a JavaScript function before IE9 ([compatibility reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11)).