# How do I select the first child of a parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to select the first child of a parent element with pure JavaScript and change some of it's CSS properties. I've tried `.firstChild` and `.childNodes[1]` methods but they do not work. This can be done with CSS `nth-child()` selector but I would like to do it with JavaScript for better browser support.

Example:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="daddy">
       <div class="child">I want select this child and change it's css property.</div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

What I've tried:

**JavaScript**

```
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daddy');
    var d = x.firstChild; // and the x.childNodes[1]
    d.style.width="5em";
```

What works:

**CSS**

```
   daddy:nth-child(1) { width: 5em; }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `.daddy .child:first-child { width: 5em; }`? Because that's supported in every browser (albeit only in IE from version 7).

Comment: Yes I have and it does work but I want to do this JavaScript only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better browser support as you asked you can use **pure CSS** by using `:first-child` selector, since it is **cross-browser** and it is **CSS 2.1**, please see this link [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) and the table below that illustrates the browser support :

[image: table first-child]

so here is a snippet with **CSS ONLY**:

```css
.child:first-child {
  /*whatever CSS you want here --
  just fot visualization and snippet :*/
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="child">I want select this child and change it's css property.</div>
  <div class="child">child 2</div>
  <div class="child">child 3</div>
  <div class="child">child 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know that `:first-child` will work quite well but what if I want to do this with JavaScript only?

Comment: why would you want this JS only when you could have a easiest/cleanest solution by using CSS only like my answer?

Comment: I agree and I will be using `:first-child` but I'm just curious to know if this can be done with Js.

Comment: you have a few answers with JS only already.. but since you are going to use the `:first-child` would you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: Sure. May I ask what good it would do to you if I mark your answer as accepted? I'm new here.

Comment: It only increases my reputation here in SO, but I said that because you told you we're going to use my answer, usually OP mark as accepted the answer that fixes the problem or the answer that OP he is going to use in his/her code ;)

Answer (score 7):

Two problems:

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object. You need to select the first element in the list.
2. `firstChild` and `childNodes` will return text nodes, not just elements. Use `.children` to access elements only:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daddy');
var d = x[0].children[0];
d.style.width="5em";
```

```html
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="child">I want to select this child and change its css property.</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but can I use `document.getElementById()` instead of the `document.getElementsByClassName()`? Will it be the same code below?

Comment: If your container *has* an ID, then yes - but in that case, you'll get a single element (not a list), so it would be `var d = x.children[0];`

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daddy');
var d = x[0].children[0];
d.style.width = '5em';
```

Or if you had multiple daddy elements you could do

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daddy');

[].forEach.call(x, function(d) {
    d.children[0].style.width = '5em';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList, it doesn't have `firstChild` or `childNodes` property, you should get the elements of the collection and then use those properties, i.e. `x[index]`.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daddy'), i = 0, j;

for (; i < x.length; i++) {
    e = x[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0; j < e.length; j++) {
        if (e[j].nodeType === 1) {
            e[j].style.width = '5em';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that only newer browsers(*including IE9*) support the `getElementsByClassName` method. If you want to support the older browsers you should either shim the method or use an alternative function. Answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i) provide several solutions.

As an alternative you can also use the `querySelectorAll` method:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.daddy > .child:first-child'))
        .forEach(function(e) {
            e.style.width = '5em';
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

IMO you should be using this:  `.daddy > .child`

The difference between the standard `X Y` and `X > Y` is that the latter will only select direct children.

Please refer to this:

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? OP isn't looking to refine a CSS selector, nor is `.daddy .child` used anywhere in the question.

Comment: All the `.child` elements are direct children of the `.daddy` element; this will do nothing to help find (only) the first child.