# Why does document.GetElementsByClassName work on local drive but not on a network drive?

Tags: javascript

(Already seen [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i) but it isn't the same issue).

This is an HTML page intended to run in a browser locally (i.e. double-click the page in File Explorer), **not served**.

The page links to a simple JS file with a few functions.  If the page and script are on a local drive, it works as expected. but when they are on a network drive, one of the functions fails with the exception 'Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'.  The function is:

```
function DisplaySection(section)
{
  var sections = document.getElementsByClassName("SECTION");
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)
  {
    sections[i].style.display = sections[i].id == section ? "block" : "none";
  }
}
```

To confirm: the JS functions are visible in both environments, and are properly connected to the document - I can step into the function that fails using F12 debugger.

Any pointers very welcome.

Comment: Is IE running in IE8 mode which does not support that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because of (in)Compatibility View in IE, which is *on* by default for intranet resources. And so IE goes into (in)Compatibility Mode, in which there is no `getElementsByClassName`.

You can try to get the IE policy* changed, or try to argue IE into submission with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3449338/157247) claims that will work), or you can use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var sections = document.querySelectorAll(".SECTION");
```

`querySelectorAll` existed all the way back in IE8, whereas `getElementsByClassName` wasn't added until IE9.

* By "policy" I mean the Active Directory policy for your organization, which can determine this IE setting.

---

Or, of course, use a web browser that *doesn't do stupid things by default*. `</rant>`

Comment: querySelectorAll didn't work either (same exception), but the meta tag did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @SimonSellick: Blech, it must have been rolling back all the way to IE7 mode. :-) Glad the meta worked!