# How to get element by class name in IE 7 & 6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an element by class name and in IE 9+ i can use document.getElementsByClassName while in IE 8 document.querySelectorAll works.

The above 2 functions are not available in IE 7 and i'm trying to use the idea in **kapa's** answer provided here [getElementsByClassName() doesn't work in old Internet Explorers like IE6, IE7, IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i)

Below is the code i'm trying `

```
function getElementsByClassNameBackwardCompatability(className) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(className);//EI 9+
    } else if (document.querySelectorAll(className)) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(className);//EI 8
    } else { // IE7 - (not working)
        var d = document, element, pattern;
        pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ',@@class, ' '), ' " + className + " ')]";
        element = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
        return  element;
    }
}`
```

It throws the error "`JavaScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.`" in IE 7

And below is how i'm using the function

```
     var ddlone = getElementsByClassNameBackwardCompatability(".myClass");
        $(ddlone).dropdownchecklist("destroy");
        $(ddlone).dropdownchecklist({ icon: {}, closeRadioOnClick: true, maxDropHeight: 150});

  $(getElementsByClassNameBackwardCompatability(".myDateClass")).each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
            });});
```

Any one how i can get this working in IE 7?

Comment: Why do you need to catch that older cat?

Comment: the big cat here has IE 11 on their machine but they run it document mode 7 :=)

Comment: Then tell the tiger not to switch over the crazy cat.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal sorry but you question isn't pertinent

Comment: @Wintermute Do you use IE6?

Comment: not me but the reasons could be many, big organizations could have a scheduled plan for the upgrade for the os

Comment: Um... why not just use jQuery to select your elements e.g. `$('.myClass')`? jQuery was intended to help with some cross-browser problems.

Comment: How many???? https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/ie6countdown/

Comment: @Mikey i have already tried that but also throws the same error in IE 7, works in IE 8+

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The function does take a class name, not a class selector - without the dot. Try calling it as

```
getElementsByClassNameBackwardCompatability(".myDateClass")
```

You really should use the [original code from that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054465/1048572), yours is different in several key aspects that cause it to not work.