# issue with running js on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this code which ie has a problem with.

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

The Developer Tools says the following line is the problem. It doesn't run any JS on my site ! So I guess it is because of this problem.  I know this could be very basic stuff...unfortunately I am not JS literate :(

```
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

The error is

Object doesn't support this property or method

Being an amateur in Js I was so happy about my site doing wonders on Chrome and Firefox - till my happiness crashed as always with ie...

Would be greatly obliged if somebody can help shed some light on this.

By the way my Doctype is declared as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

If that has to do anything with it.

Thanks in advance for any help

my site which i am developing is http://www.mylaundrywala.com ...works fine on Chrome and Firefox as I mentioned.

Comment: What version is your IE? `getElementsByClassName` only works with IE9 and higher.

Comment: Ohk...so it would be great if you could tell me an alternate to this.

Comment: @user3526204 Check out the other linked question. They do mention `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` there in the answers of alternative options too. Seeing you use IE8, `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` should be an option as it works with IE8 and up.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...will have to redo the carousel I guess. Eitherways I am not very familiar with Js. Wish me luck guys. Thanks a ton everybody !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what Internet Explorer you are testing your code. As you can see  IE9 and higher versions support that method. [Document.getElementsByClassName() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

[image: Document.getElementsByClassName]

Some one has also suggest a workaround here: [getElementsByClassName() doesn't work in old Internet Explorers like IE6, IE7, IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i)

Answer (score 1):

Old IE doesnt support getByClassName.

You can use below code to as turnaround for this

`function getElementsByClassName(className) {
      var found = [];
     var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var names = elements[i].className.split(' ');
       for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        if (names[j] == className) found.push(elements[i]);
      }
     }
     return found;
    }`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rupesh. Just one more thing. How can I get the variable x from this. Sorry I sound amateur. But I am that's y...

Comment: Hey I got that too. And now my slider is working fine on ie 8 ! Thanks a ton for the solution @Rupesh Dhadiwal