# Javascript - document.links.className?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript question that I am curious about.  When using:

```
var test = document.links(arrayNum).name;
```

Is it possible to dig deeper into specifying links?  For instance, if there is just a group of links from within a div with an id that you would like to target as opposed to all the links on the page could you write something like:

```
var test = document.getElementById('divId').links(arrayNum).name;
```

Or could I add a class to the statement to target only the links associated with it?

```
var test = document.links.className(arrayNum).name;
```

Is anything like this feasible?

Comment: Why don't you tried those things by your self... if it does not work, then you can ask question about it.

Comment: I have tried them by myself and they didn't work, hence my asking a question about it.  When it didn't work, that meant my syntax was wrong so I came here, showed what I had tried and hoped somebody could elaborate.  Correct me if I'm wrong but that seems to be the premise of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `links` collection belongs to the `document` object only, it is not on the prototype chain for elements.  It's not quite the same thing, but you can get all the `<a>` tags of a particular element using [`getElementsByTagName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(VS.85).aspx):

```
// retrieve a collection of all a elements
var test = document.getElementById('divId').getElementsByTagName("a");
```

In browsers that support it, you can use [`querySelectorAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115(VS.85).aspx):

```
// retrieve a collection of all links
var test = document.getElementById('divId').querySelectorAll("a, area");
```

Or you could use a library like jQuery or mootools to do all the <strike>hard</strike> work for you:

```
var test = $("#divId a, #divId area");
```

Comment: Thank you for the break down of this.  I am new to JQuery and didn't think of that as an option.  But this is definitely something I'll be using the future.

Comment: @Slevin: Don't forget to take a look at bobince's answer.  He offers some sound advice on the use of the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`document.links` is purely document-wide, but there are other DOM methods you can use, eg.:

```
var test= document.getElementById('divId').getElementsByTagName('a')[n].name;
```

and:

```
var test= document.getElementsByClassName('someclass').name;
```

(that one is quite new and not supported by all browsers, so if you want it to work everywhere you'll have to [add fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818865/do-we-have-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript), and be careful for the difference between live and non-live node lists.)

(Note `[]` array index syntax not `()`. And incidentally, why `name`? Typically you'd avoid `<a name>` today in favour of general-purpose `id` today.)