# What is the JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's .contents()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change class property on an iframe I use `.contents()` which is perfectly working. But I want to do this using JavaScript. My code is:

```
var $c = $('#myframe').contents();              
$c.find('.inner-wp').css('margin','0')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.contents()` on a frame returns the document within the frame. So, you're looking for:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
var c = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
```

Note: This won't work if the frame is from a different origin.
The remaining part of the code:

```
var inner_wp = c.getElementsByClassName('inner-wp');
for (var i=0; i<inner_wp.length; i++) {
    inner_wp[i].style.margin = '0';
}
```

Comment: @amit See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818865/do-we-have-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript.

Comment: Please note that `contents()` in general returns the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.