# getElementsByClassName error received in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we have getElementsByClassName in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818865/do-we-have-getelementsbyclassname-in-javascript)

I am receiving an error below in IE only, not in any other browser:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'
```

So I am assuming it does not suppose getElementByClassName in IE. My question is then what should be an equivalent to use in stead of this in example below:

```
var numb = document.getElementsByClassName('num_questions');
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1820237/921204

Comment: Look in the "Related" column in the sidebar -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var numb = $('.num_questions');
```

Answer (score 0):

[IE < 9](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) does not have `getElementsByClassName` support.

Since you are using jQuery you can achieve the same by `$('.num_questions')`